Cambiar idioma de resultado de paginación laravel 11
La siguiente es que trato de cambiar el idioma en el que se muestra el mensaje de resultado de las tablas "Showing 1 to 6 of 26 results", segun se cambia en la carpeta lang, que esta en resources, pero no tengo ninguna carpeta llamada asi, coloque el siguiente comando "php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-pagination", para publicar lo del idioma, pero no me crea una carpeta lang, si no la carpeta vendor/pagination, en donde hay ciertos archivos y uno llamado tailwind.blade.php en donde aparece el texto que se muestra en los resultados, a lo que quiero llegar es que si se cambia los textos que se muestran en ingles, y coloco unos textos en español no hay algún problema o si.
<div>
            <p class="text-sm text-gray-700 leading-5 dark:text-gray-400">
                {!! __('Showing') !!}
                @if ($paginator->firstItem())
                    <span class="font-medium">{{ $paginator->firstItem() }}</span>
                    {!! __('to') !!}
                    <span class="font-medium">{{ $paginator->lastItem() }}</span>
                @else
                    {{ $paginator->count() }}
                @endif
                {!! __('of') !!}
                <span class="font-medium">{{ $paginator->total() }}</span>
                {!! __('results') !!}
            </p>
        </div>


Haz una copia previamente, modifica lo que sea texto (lo que esté entre comillas simples como 'Showing', 'to', 'of', 'results'...) y si no te funciona, te devuelves a la copia.

para publicar las carpetas de traducción debes utilizar php artisan lang:publish, esta carpeta por lo general solo tiene unos archivos y estan con las traducciones en ingles para esto puedes utlizar Laravel Lang
Para utilizar laravel lang tienes que:

instalar el paquete con composer require --dev laravel-lang/common
añadir las traducciones con php artisan lang:add es en esto publicara las traducciones de español y de ingles.
Después tienes que actualizar tu archivo .env en a APP_LOCALE=es

Este paquete tiene las traducciones listas para la paginación y muchos otros paquetes
